# Can I use Zotac GeForce GTX 1050 Ti OC Edition ZT-P10510B-10L 4GB on my server machine with Ubuntu OS?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu, gpu-driver

In product specification they have only mentioned windows 7,8 and 10 as supported OS for Zotac GeForce GTX 1050 Ti OC Edition: https://www.zotac.com/us/product/graphics_card/zotac-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-oc-edition#spec

But I can see a Linux driver available for download on Zotac's website: https://www.zotac.com/files/download/graphics_cards?driver_type=235&g_card_series=1320&g_card_os=246&sku=ZT-P10510B-10L&skuSelect=ZT-P10510B-10L

Will I be able to use this GPU on my Ubuntu server machine? Will i need to perform some special installation for it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the link in your question led to a link to download this run file: http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/384.98/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.98.run. This is the same graphics driver as the nvidia-384 package which is in the default Ubuntu repositories for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install this Nvidia graphics driver open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-384 nvidia-settings  
sudo reboot
```

Installing this graphics driver from the default Ubuntu repositories is the recommended way to do it, because that way the nvidia-384 package will receive updates as they become available.

For altcoin mining you have a choice of either installing nvidia-cuda-tookit from the default Ubuntu repositories or downloading the latest version of NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit from the official nvidia.com website. If you choose to download the latest version of NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit from nvidia.com you will need to have Ubuntu 16.04 installed and then download the Base Installer .deb (local) file and double-click it to open it for installation in Ubuntu Software. The CUDA Toolkit Base Installer .deb package includes both the Nvidia graphics driver and NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit bundled together in one package. If the CUDA Toolkit Base Installer is not compatible with your computer's hardware, then uninstall it and try again with nvidia-384 and nvidia-cuda-tookit from the default Ubuntu repositories.

#### Ubuntu 18.04

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install  
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you. But my main question is whether this GPU " Zotac GeForce GTX 1050 Ti OC Edition" will work with Ubuntu OS? I am asking this because on the product specification they have only mentioned windows 7,8 and 10 as supported OS.

Comment: According to www.zotac.com the Zotac GeForce GTX 1050 Ti is supported for L:inux. The Zotac GeForce GTX 1050 Ti has an official download for Linux corresponding to the nvidia-384 package which is available in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. In Nvidia drivers generally the exact driver version usually is not critical as long as you install the same version or a less recent version driver. In your case the exact driver version is available in the default Ubuntu repositories, so I am optimistic that this graphics card is compatible with Ubuntu.

Comment: The question would rather be why we need a gaming GPU in  a **server**.

Comment: Going to use it for altcoin mining.