# nvidia geforce graphics drivers installation

Tags: nvidia-geforce

Is there any need to install new nvidia driver in ubuntu studio 16.04 LTS???
I just installed it and not sure what to do. I downloaded the drivers but can't install them.

Comment: I am using Zotac nvidia geforce gt 730 4 gb zone edition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Zotac GeForce GTX 1050 Ti OC Edition ZT-P10510B-10L 4GB on my server machine with Ubuntu OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/991215/can-i-use-zotac-geforce-gtx-1050-ti-oc-edition-zt-p10510b-10l-4gb-on-my-server-m) Your graphics card is compatible with the same Nvidia proprietary graphics card as in the accepted answer to the linked question. Source: https://www.zotac.com/il/files/download/graphics_cards. You don't need to insdtall Nvidia CUDA Toolkit.